# On the emulator everything works, on real divece, code not work

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

Faced a problem, I'm going through the SQL database lesson. On the emulator everything works, logs show that there is an entry in the table, on the real device - logs, no. Device - Meizu M3 Note.

```
package com.example.opimand.simplesqlite;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity  implements View.OnClickListener{

    final String LOG_TAG = "myLogs";

    Button btnAdd, btnRead, btnClear;
    EditText etName, etEmail;

    DBHelper dBhelper;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        btnAdd = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnAdd);
        btnAdd.setOnClickListener(this);

        btnRead = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnRead);
        btnRead.setOnClickListener(this);

        btnClear = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnClear);
        btnClear.setOnClickListener(this);

        etName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etName);
        etEmail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etEmail);

        dBhelper = new DBHelper(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();

        String name = etName.getText().toString();
        String email = etEmail.getText().toString();

        SQLiteDatabase db = dBhelper.getWritableDatabase();


        switch (v.getId()){
            case R.id.btnAdd:
            Log.d(LOG_TAG, "---Insert in my table---");

                cv.put("name", name);
                cv.put("email", email);

                long rowId = db.insert("mytable", null, cv);
                Log.d(LOG_TAG, "raw inserted, ID "+rowId);
                break;

            case R.id.btnRead:
                Log.d(LOG_TAG, "---Raws in my table ---");
                Cursor c = db.query("mytable",null,null,null,null,null,null);
                if (c.moveToFirst()){

                    int idColIndex = c.getColumnIndex("id");
                    int nameColIndex = c.getColumnIndex("name");
                    int emailColIndex = c.getColumnIndex("email");

                    do {
                        Log.d(LOG_TAG,
                              "ID = "+c.getInt(idColIndex)+
                        ", name = "+c.getString(nameColIndex)+
                        ", email = "+c.getString(emailColIndex));
                    } while (c.moveToNext());

                }else {
                    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "0 raws");
                    c.close();
                    break;
                }
            case R.id.btnClear:
                Log.d(LOG_TAG, "---Clear my table---");
                int clearCount = db.delete("mytable", null, null);
                Log.d(LOG_TAG, "deleted raws count ="+clearCount);
                break;
        }
        dBhelper.close();
    }

    class DBHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper{

        public DBHelper(Context context) {
            super(context, "nyDb", null, 1);

        }

        @Override
        public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

            Log.d(LOG_TAG, "---onCreateDatabase---");
            db.execSQL("create table mytable ("
            + "id integer primary key autoincrement,"
            + "name text,"
            + "email text"+");");
        }

        @Override
        public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

        }
    }
}
```

Logs from the emulator
    --- onCreate database ---
    --- Insert in mytable: ---
    row inserted, ID = 1

And these logs from the real device show an error

```
03-08 12:38:56.506 5161-5161/com.example.opimand.simplesqlite E/System: stat file error, path is /data/app/com.example.opimand.simplesqlite-2/lib/arm64, exception is android.system.ErrnoException: stat failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
03-08 12:38:57.448 5161-5215/com.example.opimand.simplesqlite E/GED: Failed to get GED Log Buf, err(0)

                                                                     [ 03-08 12:38:57.448  5161: 5215 I/         ]
                                                                     elapse(include ctx switch):3792 (ms), eglInitialize
```

Comment: are you using some external (3rd party) native libraries?

Comment: No, Everything I use is visible in the code

Answer (score 1):

> 03-08 12:38:56.506 5161-5161/com.example.opimand.simplesqlite
>   E/System: stat file error, path is
>   /data/app/com.example.opimand.simplesqlite-2/lib/arm64, exception is
>   android.system.ErrnoException: stat failed: ENOENT (No such file or
>   directory)

I think the key of your problem is in the ...**/arm64** Your application if trying to look for a 64 bits binary, which it may find in the emulator, but not in your device.

Edit- Your device is The **Meizu M3** features a MediaTek MT6750 processor with 8 ARM Cortex-A53, 64-bit CPU cores and Mali-T860 graphics. So that should not be your problem.

https://liliputing.com/2016/04/meizu-m3-is-an-octa-core-64-bit-smartphone-for-92.html

You will be able to find more information about this here:

https://github.com/realm/realm-java/issues/705

Comment: I can't found directory on   /data/app/com.example.opimand.simplesqlite-2/lib/arm64 , but application installed on phone

Comment: So you should first check what is the correct path and change that in your script.  You can install a File Manager to check this.

Comment: I do not specify in the code in which folder the database should be stored, on the other device everything works correctly.
File Manager is plugin for AndroidStudio ?

Comment: Just to be sure, the script you pasted is your whole app, and in the emulator it creates tables, insert information in the tables... and everything?

Comment: On emulator and other device, everything work fine, I can't add information in table, read and delete.

Comment: Are you using a Nexus 9? Or what is the device you are using?

Comment: >>Device - Meizu M3 Note.

Comment: I will edit my answer with a link I found about the topic, it may help you in your research

Comment: In what devices it works fine? (both real and emulators)

Comment: On HTC, API 10 work fine, on emulator Nexus API 21 too.

Answer (score 0):

You have wrongly defined your DATABASE PATH. Your database will resides inside databases folder in your application's package directory.

It should be

```
/data/data/com.example.opimand.simplesqlite-2/databases/
```

Comment: Application installed on device, but I can't found his folder.  
On other  device everything  works fine